# New reviewer, looking for clarification about what appears to be a request to critique

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question, reviews, help-center

RE: [Job description for my employment reference](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/47050/25849)

I've just been given access to the review queues and I'm seeking some clarification.  The above question appears to meet the expectation in the [Help Center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for questions that aren't allowed here.  Specifically, either of the following:

> - Proofreading requests.
> - Requests to critique your work or rephrase something. However, please do feel free to use your own writing as examples in on-topic questions.

Am I correct in that assessment?

Answer (score 6):

It's not the strongest question out there, and it's pretty borderline in the sense of asking for a critique, but it's a writing question and is more or less on topic.

We're not as stringent about topicality as, say, Worldbuilding is, though we do care about it and do enforce it.

If you look at the answers the question got, they focus on *how* to write a job description and aren't about assessing the example sentences directly.  While perhaps the OP could have worded the question more to emphasize this focus, the question is ultimately about the "how."

Comment: +1 for checking the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, this is a request to revise a piece of writing and it should be closed.

I'd also like to point out that the mods tend to be reluctant to close a question unilaterally. We'd prefer to see at least a close vote or three before stepping in with the mod hammer. (Moderator votes don't count as single votes and flat-out close the question.) This is a matter of opinion, and could change: At least one of the candidates in [the upcoming election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election) would like to close off-topic questions more quickly.

Comment: Former candidate.  That person withdrew from the election (I don't know why).